# Index page is not re rendering/refreshing on search in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

I am making a simple search in rails on the index page. My problem is that on debug I get the correct results but they don't show on the frontend.

```
def index
 if !params[:category].present? and !params[:title].present?
  @services = Service.take(4)
 else
   if params[:category] != "Find Service" and params[:title].present?
    @services = Service.where(category: params[:category], title: params[:title]).take(4)
   elsif params[:category] == "Find Service" and params[:title].present?
    @services = Service.where(title: params[:title]).take(4)
   elsif params[:category] != "Find Service" and !params[:title].present?
    @services = Service.where(category: params[:category]).take(4)
   else
    @services = Service.take(4)
   end
  end
 end
```

My view index.html.erb

```
<%= form_with(url: "services", method: "get") do |form| %>
 <div class="banner-input" style="margin-top">
   <div class="listing-sort listing-sort--main-listing" style="width: 50%;float: left; border-radius: 6px; border: 2px solid white; background: transparent; padding: 0px;">
     <input type="submit" value="" class="main-listing__form-field agent-submit" style="width: 10% ;float:right">   
     <%= form.text_field "title", id: "search_agent", class: "main-listing__form-field ", placeholder: "Search by Name or Location...", style: "width: 75% ;float:right; background: transparent; color: white!;" %>  
     <div class="listing-sort__inner" style="float:left;margin: 0px; width: 25%; padding: 0px;">
       <p class="listing-sort__sort">
        <%= form.select("category",options_for_select(["Find Service", "Assembly", "Carpet Cleaning", "Electrical", "House Cleaning", "HVAC", "Handyman", "IT", "Junk Removal", "Lawn Care","Moving", "Painting", "Plumbing", "Staging", "Photography", "Videography", "Inspectors"], :selected => "Find Service"), {include_blank: false}, { :class => 'ht-field listing-sort__field' }) %>
       </p><!-- .listing-sort__sort -->
     </div><!-- .listing-sort__inner -->
   </div><!-- .listing-sort -->

 </div>
<% end %>

<section style="margin-top: 50px">
 <h2 style="margin-left: 15px; padding-bottom: 30px; font-size: 24px;">Recently viewed & more</h2>
 <% @services.each do |service| %>
  <%= render 'services/service_card', :f => service %>
 <% end %>
</section>

<section class="jumbotron"style="margin-top: 50px">
 <h2 style="margin-left: 15px; padding-bottom: 30px; font-size: 24px;">Pro SEM services
 </h2>
 <% @services.each do |service| %>
  <%= render 'services/service_card', :f => service %>
 <% end %>
</section>
```

This is _service_card

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3" style="padding-bottom: 10px">
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box-img">
    <img src="assets/MobileApps.png">
  </div>
  <div class="user-detail-main">
    <div class="user-detail-img">
      <img src="assets/MobileApps.png">
    </div>
    <div class="user-detail">
      <a><h3><%= f.user.profile.first.first_name %></h3></a>
      <p>Level 1 Seller</p>
    </div>
    <div class="user-detail-para">
      <% byebug %>
      <p><%= f.description %></p>
    </div>
    <div style="padding-top: 50px;">
      <i class="fas fa-star" style="color: #ffbf00"></i> (5)
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="user-detail-footer">
    <div class="heart-icon">
      <i class="fas fa-heart" style="color: #c6c6c6"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-bars" style="color: #c6c6c6"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="user-value">
      <p>Starting At $ <%= f.packages.first.price%></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please help me regarding this. Looking forward. It is working fine without search, but with search it doesn't update the results and show same results.

Comment: I'm sorry. Do I miss somethings. I cannot find the ```@services``` in your view.

Comment: I have just added the missing code @TsaiKoga

Comment: I just want my index action/view to be re-rendered. But it is not re-rendering/refreshing. It goes into the controller with correct params, executes the correct if statement, returns back the correct results in @services in the view, but doens't show them as the page is not reloaded.

Comment: Two things to check : 
1. Check the log file to see if the service card partial being is logged there.
2. When you make the request, watch the network tab of the browser developer tools to see what was the server response for that request.

If both of the above are good, my guess is that Turbolinks is causing the issue. Answers to above 2 questions will provide better info.

Comment: 1) Log file shows service card. 2) Under the network tab, when I see the preview, there is the updated response without any css. And when I see response tab, I see the html css code and the service is updated.

Comment: I get an updated response at the frontend, but the page doesn't show it. It neither reloads nor refreshes on the form submission. The request goes back, the response comes, but no change on the page

Comment: @SalmanHaseebSheikh may be it cannot find the partial file. Check your partial file path and filename is right.